# GORM CreateInBatches with Embedded Struct Error

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have the following struct (truncated for readability)

```
type Schedule struct {
    ID              int  
    UserId          int
    User            User    `gorm:"embedded;foreignKey:UserId;references:UserId"`
}
```

And then my User struct (again, truncated for readability):

```
type User struct {
    ID         int
    UserId     int
    IsActive   bool 
}
```

I'm attempting a `CreateInBatches` on the `Schedule` struct (as `[]Schedule`). But when I do, the insert query is attempting to also insert the values from the `User` struct.

Example (partial code) for insertion:

```
err := db.Transaction(func(tx *gorm.DB) error {
    if err := tx.CreateInBatches(&schedules, len(schedules)).Error; err != nil {
        return err //Rollback
    }
}
```

For completion sake, here is the error:

> Error Inserting Schedule Batch: Error 1054: Unknown column 'is_active'
> in 'field list'

Is there a tag or anything that I can do to omit the User struct from the insert query? When I output the query, it is showing the
`INSERT INTO schedule (schedule columns..., [additional user struct columns])`

I've also tried the field permission tags per the documentation [here](https://gorm.io/docs/models.html#Field-Level-Permission)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is that you are using `embedded` tag for `User` inside `Schedule` struct. It should work as expected when you remove it. You can read about it in [docs](https://gorm.io/docs/models.html#Embedded-Struct)

So your `Schedule` struct should look like this:

```golang
type Schedule struct {
    ID              int  
    UserId          int
    User            User `gorm:"foreignKey:UserId;references:UserId"`
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I need the embedded for the select queries when doing joins. Otherwise it won't populate the sub object. Any thoughts on being able to use both?

Comment: Why do you need embedded for select queries?

Comment: Unless I'm doing it wrong, it won't populate the sub object when you join on the query. I will investigate from that end to see if my join is correct and filling the objects correctly

Comment: You can use Preload functionality for that. Here are docs for it: https://gorm.io/docs/preload.html#Preload
Please accept this answer if it solved your issue

Comment: I was able to get my joins to work without using embed or preload (since preload runs multiple queries and will be extremely inefficient with the amount of data I will be working with). The clue was the embedded on the object.